# Did Adam establish a justice system?

Tags: history, mitzvah, beit-din-court, noachide-laws, adam

One of the [mitzvot](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1188354/jewish/Melachim-uMilchamot-Chapter-9.htm) given to Adam was to establish laws and courts.

Was Adam successful in setting up a working justice system, and if so, do we know any practical details of how it operated and/or for how long it was in operation? For example, it seems pretty clear that it was no longer operating at the time of Abraham, but would it have still been active at Babel? Just before the Flood? At the time of Noah's birth? Did it die with Adam?

Comment: Just to note that, per Sanhedrin 56b, the idea that this commandment was given to Adam is a minority view.